# Why does remuxing a VOB fix freezing issues?

Tags: video, dvd, mpeg, multiplexing, vob

I am currently transcoding video data from a Video DVD to x264 MP4 files, but the original MPEG-2 streams seem to have some strange problems. This video DVD is of a home-made digital TV recording (DVB-S) using a PVR, and subsequently burned to a standard DVD-R. The recorded programmes play back flawlessly in my standalone DVD player.

After checking one of the transcoded MP4 files, I noticed that at
certain points—always the same frames, irrespective of the range of
the original video I'm encoding—there is a weird stutter in the video.
One frame freezes for about a second. The number of frames remains
correct so there is no audio sync issue, it is just that about 20
frames are replaced by duplicates of one specific frame. This seems to
happen regardless of the software I use. I have tried Avidemux 2.6.3
with native MPEG-2 decoding or serving frames through Avisynth 2.6.0,
and also VirtualDub 1.9.11 with the MPEG-2 plugin. All three methods
introduced the same number of duplicates of the same frame at the same
position every time.

Examining the source VOB, I checked this specific section of the
stream and noticed that there is a slight stutter in playback too
(tested using Windows Media Player, VideoLAN, MPlayer, and AviDemux'
internal preview), but it is **not** the exact same freeze. It happens
about a second earlier in the stream than in the transcoded file, and
freezes for about half as long (~10 frames). This also happened
irrespective of whether I played the original video directly from the
DVD-R or after copying the VOB file to hard disk, so it's not the
drive that's at fault.

Following the suggestion of a friend, I demultiplexed the VOB into its
elementary M2V and AC3 streams, and then directly remultiplexed the
two into a new MPEG-PS file. Indeed, the stutter disappeared from both
direct playback of the remuxed file, and the
transcodes that I generate from it.

So, the symptom of the problem is solved, but I wonder why simply demuxing and remuxing the original video was enough? Is some sort of index being rebuilt in the process, solving a problem inherent to the original data? But then, why is the freeze different after transcoding, even across different decoders and encoders; and why do I notice no freeze when playing it back on a standalone TV DVD player?